# android, how to find out what channel the notification is belong to

Tags: push-notification, android-notifications

in the android app when having active notifications it can use

```
NotificationManager.getActiveNotifications()
```

to get the active notifications.

If the app configured with multiple notification groups and channels, how to find out what channel the active notification is belong to?

Answer (score 1):

```
StatusBarNotification[] list = notificationManager.getActiveNotifications();
for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
  StatusBarNotification activeNoti = list[i];
  Notification noti = activeNoti.getNotification();
  //to get channel ID
  String channelId = noti.getChannelId();
}
```

**Note:** `notificationManager.getActiveNotifications()` will only give the notification build by your app (it will not return the other notification which is not build by your app)